# Is there a regular expession or similar simple approach for checking whether a MediaWiki PageTitle is valid?

Tags: java, python, mediawiki

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_title states a lot of conditions for what a MediaWiki pageTitle may not contain. It looks like checking whether a string is a valid MediaWiki PageTitle is not quite easy with this approach.

**What would be a regular expression or similar simple approach to check whether a page Title is valid?**

The best i could find so far is some Java Code (from https://github.com/MER-C/wiki-java/blob/master/src/org/wikipedia/Wiki.java). My target language is python, though.

```
    /**
     *  Convenience method for normalizing MediaWiki titles. (Converts all
     *  underscores to spaces).
     *  @param s the string to normalize
     *  @return the normalized string
     *  @throws IllegalArgumentException if the title is invalid
     *  @throws IOException if a network error occurs (rare)
     *  @since 0.27
     */
    public String normalize(String s) throws IOException
    {
        // remove leading colon
        if (s.startsWith(":"))
            s = s.substring(1);
        if (s.isEmpty())
            return s;

        int ns = namespace(s);
        // localize namespace names
        if (ns != MAIN_NAMESPACE)
        {
            int colon = s.indexOf(":");
            s = namespaceIdentifier(ns) + s.substring(colon);
        }
        char[] temp = s.toCharArray();
        if (wgCapitalLinks)
        {
            // convert first character in the actual title to upper case
            if (ns == MAIN_NAMESPACE)
                temp[0] = Character.toUpperCase(temp[0]);
            else
            {
                int index = namespaceIdentifier(ns).length() + 1; // + 1 for colon
                temp[index] = Character.toUpperCase(temp[index]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        {
            switch (temp[i])
            {
                // illegal characters
                case '{':
                case '}':
                case '<':
                case '>':
                case '[':
                case ']':
                case '|':
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s + " is an illegal title");
                case '_':
                    temp[i] = ' ';
                    break;
            }
        }
        // https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization_considerations
        String temp2 = new String(temp).trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        return Normalizer.normalize(temp2, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    }
```

Comment: It's probably fairly hopeless. A lot of it depends on per-wiki configuration, too. You'd have to know what namespaces the wiki has, for example.

Comment: @Tgr - thanks for looking into this. This is for a frontend that has full access to the backend wikis the main reason for the check is to avoid vulnerabilities that might arise from code camouflaged as pagetitle. Is this risk fully mitigated by excluding the illegal chars?

Comment: If you mean XSS attacks, banning `<>` is probably a good idea. In some circumstances, `&`, quotes or space can be used as an attack vector, those are all valid title characters though; you have to ensure titles are escaped properly when used. If you are writing JS code that runs on the wiki, `mw.Html` has a bunch of escaping functions. Also, `mw.Title` has some fairly sophisticated validation (not 100% equivalent with the backend logic, but comes close).

Comment: Since i have some control on the backend wikis I could modify the "legality" of pagetitles and e.g. disallow quotes and & also I am a bit afraid of escape characters like % - so it also depends at which state of url decoding the process happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you can call the target wiki API to do the normalisation, then this is an example of API call that normalises page titles:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Project:article_B&format=json&formatversion=2

The normalised title ill be in `/query/normalized/0/to`. You can send several titles to normalise at once separating them with `|`.

The example is taken from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Example_2:_Title_normalization.